# Secure communication from React Landing Page with Rails Backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, http, authentication

I'm building a Landing Page in React where a visitor submits some data (including name and phone) and this data is sent over HTTP to a Rails 4.2 Backend.

Now, in order for the Landing Page to be able to POST data to the backend, there needs to be some sort of authentication, as only a registered staff member should have access to the data. The Rails backend currently uses regular Devise user/password login to the backend.

I thought about making a dummy account and hardcode an authorization token on the POST header from the landing page, but this is obviously a big security flaw as anyone can see the hardcoded token when they submit the form.

How can I secure the Landing Page to send / receive data to the backend server in a user-agnostic way (since visitors don't make accounts, they just fill a form with their details)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not rails user. But as for your API, like almost all the RESTful API backend, I would assume that rails has the concept of public/private API. I would make the API for getting data from the user public, so that people can send their information without authentication and the other API routes private.

In java spring framework, I can allow an API route to accessible by everyone, like login and generic(no private info) API routes and every other API routes are private which requires Authentication(like an auth-token).

Answer (score 0):

When, you do the login flow and the user has entered the password and hit send, Once your backend authenticates the details, you would have to create an signed authorization token using maybe JWT** ( Json web token ) and send this authorization token to the front-end.

Then, Whenever the front-end makes a call to the backend, it has to attach this token in the header before making the API call. And the back-end should de-code the token to find out which user is requesting it and if the ttl* is within the limits as the issuing token.

If both the cases pass, the back-end should send the requested data or it should send a HTTP CODE - 403/Forbidden, which should then be handled in the front-end to logout the user and open up the login page again.

*(Time to live calculated based on the hours this token is valid from the time of issuing/login)

** JWTs are basically base-64 encoded data ( and signed with a unique key by your backend ) of the user's data. A decoded JWT token of a user would most likely look like this :

```
{ 
    userIs : "0000-aa12-bb43-cd18", 
    userName : "Some name", 
    ttl : "Time to live of this token" 
}
```

Comment: As stated, the user does not create an account. It only enters some info and then the form in the landing page sends the values to the backend. No account is created.

Comment: @Doge if there is no account being created, then what sort of authentication can you do?. Instead of authentication, If you want to increase the security of this transaction then use HTTPS for your app or if your goal is to ensure that the data sent to your server is from your website only, enforce a strong CORS policy that will only allow data that comes from your website's ORIGIN header. Kindly change your question accordingly, I don't think its related to authentication.